# How to make \cite command cite 'author-pages' via biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

How to create a biblatex cite style 'author-pages' (just like 'author-year' style)
with hyperlink? e.g. **(Ben, 41)**---single citation, **(Ben, 41; 43-45)**---multiple citations

I think the command should be able to grab info from the .bib so there is no need to manually input something like this: `\cite[pages]{key}`

After browsing the manual, I got the following workaround:

```
\newcommand{\acite}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1},   \citefield{#1}{pages})}
\newcommand{\bcite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}, \citefield{#1}{pages}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
{\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
        \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}}
    {}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

However, that workaround won't generate hyperlink for 'pages'. Also, it becomes quite untidy if I want to cite multiple sources. So, I want to have a solution that is more similar to the built-in `\cite` command.

Answer (score 1):

The `pages` field of entries in a `.bib` file is used for the page range of the bibliographic entry *as a whole*. The field is commonly used for the `@article`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` entry types which are not self-contained publications, but part of a journal, collection or proceedings.

Contrary to that, the pages/page ranges that may be added as (first) optional argument to a citaton command (e.g., `\cite[41, 43--45]{Ben}`) indicate the location of a *specific thought* in the bibliographic entry. This data is not part of the `.bib` file. Because of that (at least, unless you can provide a link to a specific page of a ressource available online), it's not useful to make a citation's optional page/page range argument part of a hyperlink.

Comment: Make sense. So there is no need to include the specific pages in the .bib file.

Comment: I re-read the biblatex manual. It says that 'pages' is  field (range) One or
more page numbers or page ranges. If the work is published as part of another
one, such as an article in a journal or a collection, this field holds the
relevant page range in that other work. It may also be used to limit the
reference to a specific part of a work (a chapter in a book, for example). So it's still resonable to get the 'author-pages' citation style. (mla style)

Comment: @user21210: It is possible, though somewhat unusual, to include only a chaper of a book (say, p. 41--45) as bibliography entry. Then this chapter is the entry " as a whole". Still, information about specific thoughts in this chapter (say, p. 41) is tied to single citations, and not part of the `.bib` file.